# pandas histogram with by: possible to make axes uniform?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the option to generate a separate histogram of a value for each group in a data frame like so (example code from documentation)

```
data = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))
data.hist(by=np.random.randint(0, 4, 1000), figsize=(6, 4))
```

This is great, but what I am not seeing is a way to set and standardize the axes. Is this possible?

To be specific, I would like to specify the x and y axes of the plots so that the y axis in particular has the same range for all plots. Otherwise it can be hard to compare distributions to one another.

Comment: What you mean by "set and standardize the axes"? It looks to me like the axes are set and they are standard enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass `kwds` to hist and it will pass them along to appropriate sub processes.  The relevant ones here are `sharex` and `sharey`

```
data = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))
data.hist(by=np.random.randint(0, 4, 1000), figsize=(6, 4),
          sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

[image]